# boost::asio::io_service destructor runs very long time

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm novice in boost::asio and have the first own troubles.
I create a simple Host resolver (see full code below).

Problem 1.
In case of lost Internet connection, my host resolver stops resolving after the first enter into deadline_timer.
My assumption, that "localhost" must be resolved at any time. But "localhost" are not resolved after timeout during resolving google.us (for example, we unplugged Ethernet jack).
The same behaviour in case of resolving unexisted TLD (for example, google.usd instead google.us).

Problem 2.
In case of lost Internet connection, destructor io_service runs very long (usually, 5 seconds).

What's wrong?

I use VS2012, boost 1.54

File hostresolver.h

```
pragma once

#include <set>

#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver_iterator.hpp>

typedef std::set<unsigned long> hostresolver_result_container;

class hostresolver
{
public:
    hostresolver(boost::asio::io_service* io_service);
    ~hostresolver(void);

    boost::asio::io_service* ios_ptr;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;

    volatile bool is_completed;
    bool is_timeout;
    std::string hostname;
    hostresolver_result_container result;

    void on_timeout(const boost::system::error_code &err);
    void start_resolve(const char* hostname, int timeout_seconds);
    void finish_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator);

private:
    void stop();
};
```

File hostresolver.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "hostresolver.h"

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

hostresolver::hostresolver(boost::asio::io_service* io_service) : 
    resolver_(*io_service), timer_(*io_service), is_completed(false), is_timeout(false)
{
    ios_ptr = io_service;
}

hostresolver::~hostresolver(void)
{
}

void hostresolver::start_resolve(const char* hostname, int timeout_second)
{
    this->hostname.assign(hostname);

    timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(timeout_second));
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&hostresolver::on_timeout, this, _1));

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(hostname, "http");
    resolver_.async_resolve(query,
                            boost::bind(&hostresolver::finish_resolve, this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));

    do
    {
        ios_ptr->run_one();
    } 
    while (!is_completed);
}

void hostresolver::stop()
{
    resolver_.cancel();
    timer_.cancel();
    is_completed = true;
}

void hostresolver::on_timeout(const boost::system::error_code &err) 
{
    if ((!err) && (err != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted))
    {
        is_timeout = true;
        stop();
    }
}

void hostresolver::finish_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        while (endpoint_iterator != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator())
        {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
            if (endpoint.address().is_v4())
            {
                result.insert(endpoint.address().to_v4().to_ulong());
            }
            endpoint_iterator++;
        }
    }

    stop();
}
```

File main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "hostresolver.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "iteration: " << i << std::endl;

        {
            hostresolver hres(&ios);
            hres.start_resolve("localhost", 1);
            if (hres.result.size() == 0)
                std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
        }

        {
            hostresolver hres(&ios);
            hres.start_resolve("google.usd", 1);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After returning from `run_once`, the `io_service` would most likely enteres the "stopped" state. Thus, you should call `ios_ptr->reset()` prior to calling `run_once()` again. Quoting from `run_once` reference:

> [Return Value: The number of handlers that were executed. A zero return
>   value implies that the io_service object is stopped (the stopped()
>   function returns true). Subsequent calls to run(), run_one(), poll()
>   or poll_one() will return immediately unless there is a prior call to
>   reset().](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one/overload1.html)

Comment: io_service::reset must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one().

Comment: @user1215838 "...when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the io_service being stopped or running out of work"